# Changed value in numpy array based on index and on criteria

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, indexing

I have a numpy array:

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]])

>> arr
[[ 1  2  3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10]]
```

I want to take a portion of the array based on indices (not slices):

```
ix = np.ix_([0, 1], [0, 2])
>> arr[ix]

[[1 3]
 [6 8]]
```

And I want to modify those elements in the original array, which would work if I did this:

```
arr[ix] = 0
>> arr
[[ 0  2  0  4  5]
 [ 0  7  0  9 10]]
```

But I only want to change them if they follow a specific condition, like if they are lesser than `5`. I am trying this:

```
subarr = arr[ix]
subarr[subarr < 5] = 0
```

But it doesn't modify the original one.

```
>> arr
[[ 1  2  3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10]]

>> subarr
[[0 0]
 [6 8]]
```

I am not sure why this is not working, since both accessing the array by indices with `np.ix_` and using a mask `subarr < 5` should return a view of the array, not a copy.

Comment: Hint: look at arr[ix][arr[ix]<5]  ...

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel this would not change the arr value .

Comment: I am not saying this, just looking at the dimension seems it is not the same object. Hence I suspect not referencing the arr one. Still looking at the answer.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel so what are you saying?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21502377/5625981 This answer explains that numpy always returns a copy if "fancy indexing"  is used.

Comment: @jdamp So what are my options here to do what I am trying to do? And how does `arr[ix] = 0` well then, if a copy instead of a view is returned?

Comment: @dabadaba it's a requirement do not make slices?

Comment: @H.Tacon well indices are not guaranteed to be contiguous, so I _have_ to use `np.ix_`.

Comment: it is explained there: https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel that article does not explain how to solve the problem when you need a view when using fancy indexing, it just explains the differences between views and copies and when you will get each.

Comment: I posted the original answer with np.where and gave you the article for understanding the difference of views, fancy indexing (which helped me as well).

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel I didn't see your other answer. I think you first posted one and then deleted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fancy indexing returns a copy; hence your original array will not be updated. You can use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to update your values:

```
arr[ix] = np.where(arr[ix] < 5, 0, arr[ix])

array([[ 0,  2,  0,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10]])
```

Comment: Awesome. I guess the trick here is to use lvalue indexing to make an assignment effective as per explained [here](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html).

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel, Oh sorry. I didn't see your post

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
arr[ix] = 0
```

The python interpreter does `arr.__setitem__(ix, 0)` hence modifying the original object.

On the second case `subarr` is independent of `arr`, it is a **copy** of the subset of arr. You then modify this copy.